# How to fix "Host name lookup for [server name] failed" after upgrading to postman 5.2.0

Tags: http, postman

After upgrading to Postman v5.2.0 I get the error "Host name lookup for [server name] failed"...

When executing the request with IP adresses it works.

I already tried to manually set/unset the proxy under Settings->Proxy and also tried experimenting with the "System Proxy" setting, but nothing changs - the error persists. As the server is in my local network, the proxy should be bypassed anyway...

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm using Postman v5.2.0 and it works without meet your problem. It sounds like a network environment issue.

Comment: I already tried reinstalling postman with no effect whatsoever... With the old Version name resolution worked fine... Also external servers are reachable (e.g. GET http://www.google.com) and work fine...

Comment: I can access both local server and external server. My Postman is running on Mac OS 10.12.6